# "Find Selected Text in Workspace..." disabled in Xcode 4 context menu

Tags: xcode4

This has been bugging me for a while. In Xcode 4, sometimes this menu item is enabled, sometimes it is disabled. I cannot figure out why it is ever disabled, and there seems to be nothing at all on Google about this.

Comment: this problem is still present in the 4.3.1 release

Comment: this problem is still present in the 6.4 release...

Answer (score 6):

I have this same problem.  If I click on the "Show assistant editor" button (the middle button in the list of Editor buttons located in the upper-right hand corner) and then back again to "Standard Editor" (the left-most button in the list of Editor buttons) then the "Find selected text in workspace..." function is enabled.  But I have to do this often, but only in the projects I created before Xcode 4.  So I think some setting in the project was not created properly when Xcode 4 converted it over.

Comment: This problem has occurred in a new Xcode 4 project.  The toggling trick does work but is a major pain in the ass.  Also, you can't highlight text in the debug output window and search for it anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I have found if you just right click on the word, without selecting it prior, then the menu selection will be enabled. This seems to be more prevalent in xCode 4.4.1. I have also noticed that when you select other words will "trigger" the menu to enable also. Hope this helps.